# Why NPOI xlsx file generation does not work on Linux Server

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, npoi

I created a web site using asp.net core. When action method having NPOI library code called, it is not responding the excel file. But it works in windows development environment.

Comment: *"... and i fixed the problem."* - so what is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I checked server logs, I noticed that NPOI library dependenct libgdiplus is not intalled.

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgdiplus

I tried this code to install on linux server and i fixed the problem.